# linking to linux shared libraries

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to install opendkim on amazon linux ec2 instance. When compiling from source I get:
configure: error: no strlcpy/strlcat found
so I installed libbsd from source. once that is installed I can go to the man page of strlcat and strlcpy but I can't access those functions. I verified that the shared libraries are installed. The output of the libbsd install stated to use one of the 4 options:

```
If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR' flag during linking and do at least one of the following:

  - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

I ran

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
```

Additionally my /etc/ld.so.conf contains

```
 include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

and my /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libbsd.conf contains

```
/usr/local/lib/libbsd
```

Lastly checking my libbsd library nm -D /usr/local/lib/libbsd.so contains:

```
000000000000de30 T strlcat
000000000000ded0 T strlcpy
```

So my questions how do I either, expose strlcat and strlcpy to the command line? Or how to I do the "use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag" option, or in general what am i doing wrong in linking to shared libraries? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So wasn't ever able to link against the libraries but I was able to resolve the dependencies. The binary rpm from centos installed perfectly :

```
sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/l/libbsd-0.6.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
 sudo yum localinstall ./libbsd-0.6.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/l/libbsd-devel-0.6.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall ./libbsd-devel-0.6.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```